# How to publish python package to test.pypi.org with poetry?

Tags: python, pypi, python-poetry

I'd like to publish my package to https://test.pypi.org/ before publishing it for real to https://pypi.org/. How can I do it with [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/)?

Answer (score 2):

Just execute this steps in directory that holds your poetry package.

1. Version your package

   ```sh
   $ poetry version 0.1.0
   ```
2. Build package

   ```sh
   $ poetry build
   ```
3. Configure test repository

   ```sh
   $ poetry config repositories.testpypi https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
   ```
4. Publish package

   ```sh
   $ poetry publish -r testpypi -u <username> -p <password> --dry-run
   $ poetry publish -r testpypi -u <username> -p <password>
   ```